# NHibernate, adding children via parent vs setting reference to parent on children

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm currently working on my first NHibernate project.

To test it out I am building an entity graph and that graph I try to persist to the database. When I add children to the parent via the add on the IList the insert is not working in the database because I get null column exceptions on the database (code snippet 1)

1. When I set a reference on the child to the parent it is working (though this feels not natural for me, see code snippet
2. Is this normal behavior or am I doing something wrong?

**Snippet 1:**

```
var country = new Country();
var countryLocale = new CountryLocale { LangCode = "nl-nl", Name = "Nederland" };
country.CountryLocales.Add(countryLocale);

var city = new City();
var cityLocale = new CityLocale { LangCode = "nl-nl", Name = "Amsterdam" };
city.CityLocales.Add(cityLocale);
country.Cities.Add(city);
```

**Snippet 1 Error:**

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'CountryId', table
>   'ArtWorld.dbo.City';  column does not allow nulls. INSERT
>   fails.\r\nThe statement has been terminated.

**snippet 2:**

```
var country = new Country();

var countryLocale = new CountryLocale { Country = country,LangCode = "nl-nl", 
                                        Name = "Nederland" };
var city = new City{Country = country};

var cityLocale = new CityLocale { City = city, LangCode = "nl-nl", 
                                        Name = "Amsterdam" };

session.SaveOrUpdate(country);
```

City and CityLocale Map:

```
public class CityMap : ClassMap<City>
{
    public CityMap()
    {
        Table("City");
        Id(x => x.Id);
        References(x => x.Country).Column("CountryId").Cascade.SaveUpdate();
        HasMany(x => x.CityLocales).KeyColumn("CityId").Cascade.SaveUpdate();
    }
}

public class CityLocaleMap : ClassMap<CityLocale>
{
    public CityLocaleMap()
    {
        Table("City_Locale");
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.LangCode).Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.Name).Not.Nullable();
        References(x => x.City).Column("CityId").Cascade.SaveUpdate();
    }
}
```

this is my Country/Countrylocale map:

```
public class CountryMap : ClassMap<Country>
{
    public CountryMap()
    {
        Table("Country");
        Id(x => x.Id);
        HasMany(x => x.Cities).KeyColumn("CountryId").Cascade.SaveUpdate();
        HasMany(x => x.CountryLocales).KeyColumn("CountryId").Cascade.SaveUpdate();
    }

}

public class CountryLocaleMap :ClassMap<CountryLocale>
{
    public CountryLocaleMap()
    {
        Table("Country_Locale");
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.LangCode).Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.Name).Not.Nullable();
        References(x => x.Country).Column("CountryId").Cascade.SaveUpdate();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NHibernate Mapping changes :

On the `Country` side you have

```
  HasMany(x => x.CountryLocales).KeyColumn("CountryId").Cascade.SaveUpdate()
```

On the CountryLocale side you have

```
References(x => x.Country).Column("CountryId").Cascade.SaveUpdate();
```

One of the relations should be marked as inverse using `.Inverse()`.

The `.Cascase.SaveUpdate()` makes sure that NHibernate manages the life cycle of the child entity `CountryLocale` when a transient child is added to the parent `Country`'s list of `CountryLocales`. If you dont want to explicitly handle the life cycle of CountryLocale yourself , I would suggest to mark the Many-To-One side from `CountryLocale` -> `Country` as `Inverse`.

There are two ways you could make your referencing `Country` in `CountryLocale` less of a *sour eye* and ***more*** intutive

**If Country manages the Locales**

Add a method in `Country` which will manage the Locales which are being added. A client (user of `Country` and `CountryLocale` need not explicitly play with the references)

```
public virtual bool AddCountryLocales(CountryLocale locale)
{
        if(!this.CountryLocales.Contains(locale))
        {
              locale.Country =this;
              this.CountryLocales.Add(locale);
              return true;  
        }
        return false;
}
```

**CountryLocale is more domain driven**

By redefining it such that you cannot have a `CountryLocale` without a `Country`

```
public class CountryLocale
{
    public CountryLocale(Country country)
    {
         this.Country = country;
    }

    //you need a no-agrument constructor for NHibernate
    protected CountryLocale()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your extensive answer. It helped me a lot.